# Programmatically Open Dialogs in Powerpoint

Tags: c#, office-interop, powerpoint-2007

could somebody tell me how to open the font selector, language selector dialogs, etc. programmatically in a powerpoint 2007 add-in? In addition to that I need the returnvalues from the dialogs (i.e. the fontname, etc.)

THANK YOU

Comment: why do you need it? whith what do you want to open it? questions...

Comment: I wrote a ppt toolkit that replaces the font of every textbox and modifies the language properties.

Comment: I've got a similar add-in. While you can execute any of the menu controls, you get no return values, so that won't help.  You'll need to create your own dialog.  Be a bit cautious ... you'll need to know the langIDs for the languages you want to support.  MS documents these in several places; some of the entries are incorrect.  Check the hex values against the decimal values given; if they don't match, find different docs.  Handing PPT a bogus language value will make it act nuts in the most amazing variety of ways.

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing special in VSTO that can do it for you, you will have to use wpf/winform, you may have a look at fontdialog class

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late. This works for me in 2010 - please see this post

[PowerPoint Open "Record Slide Show" Dialog and detect if Presentation has a recording c# addin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811237/powerpoint-open-record-slide-show-dialog-and-detect-if-presentation-has-a-reco)

You will need to find the equivalent for "RecordNarration" but it should work for you.

Trev