# PowerPoint Open "Record Slide Show" Dialog and detect if Presentation has a recording c# addin

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

I am developing a PowerPoint AddIn and have been asked to add a reminder to the user to "Record Slide Show".

Can anyone help me find out how to programmatically open the "Record Slide Show" dialog box and also how to detect if the user has already added a recording to the slide show please?

Many thanks

Trevor

Comment: Which version of powerpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this to work.

In the ribbon I have added the following:

```
public static void callRecordDialog()
{
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("RecordNarration");
}
```

then in the form I have called it like this...

```
private void btnVoiceOverYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    vCreateRibbon.callRecordDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

took ages to find that!

hope it helps someone else

Trev